Trouble Fetching Data from MongoDB Atlas in Full Stack Blog Deployed on Vercel and Netlify
I've developed a full-stack blog website as part of my learning journey in web development. I'm relatively new to this field. The website includes an admin panel where admins can manage blog posts by deleting, updating, and creating new ones. Everything functions smoothly on my local host. However, upon hosting the website on both Vercel and Netlify, I encountered an issue. While the front end displays blog posts correctly on the home page, indicating that it's working fine, the changes made through the admin panel (such as updates, creations, and deletions) do not reflect on the website. Surprisingly, these operations are successfully executed in the MongoDB Atlas database.
Even when I make GET requests via Postman, the data retrieved is not updated. Any insights into resolving this discrepancy would be greatly appreciated.
here is the link to repo: https://github.com/Saif-Arshad/Full-stack-OmniBlog

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
